# Magento 2.1.2 search products by ids in CatalogSearch

Tags: magento2, products, search

I am getting product ids from external product search system. I need them to be the result of search done through CatalogSearch.

I thought of adding a filter to *searchCriteria* in **_renderFiltersBefore()** function located in

[app/code/Magento/CatalogSearch/Model/ResourceModel/Fulltext/Collection.php](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/b4c3bfdf9caf087e6092780786c36b8abad6f5d0/app/code/Magento/CatalogSearch/Model/ResourceModel/Fulltext/Collection.php)

like

```
$this->filterBuilder->setField('entity_id');
$this->filterBuilder->setValue([1,2,24]); // <-- product ids
$this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter($this->filterBuilder->create());
```

but it doesn't seem there's a filter that could select products by ids.

I have also found **addIdFilter($productId, $exclude = false)** function in
[app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Collection.php](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/b4c3bfdf9caf087e6092780786c36b8abad6f5d0/app/code/Magento/CatalogSearch/Model/ResourceModel/Fulltext/Collection.php)
but can't find a way to make use of it in CatalogSearch.